# Hatcher 2.2 exercise 10

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the quotient space of $S^2$ under the identifications $x\sim −x$ for $x$ in equator $S^1$.
I want to compute the fundamental group and homology groups $H_i(X)$. I also want to repeat this exercise for $S^3$ with antipodal points of the equatorial $S^2$ contained in $S^3$ identified.

Yikes, thanks in advance for any help.  :P

Comment: (Just to make a useless comment) This space has a standard name that you will find out at some point if you haven't already.

Comment: @MichaelHardy what's the name?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can decompose $X$ as the union of the upper and lower hemispheres (with antipodal points on the equator identified), each of which is homeomorphic to $B^2$ with antipodal points on its boundary identified. Thus each of the components in the decomposition is $RP^2$.  Their intersection is the equator with antipodal points identified, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Then use Seifert-van Kampen to get the fundamental group, and Mayer-Vietoris to get the homology groups. An analogous decomposition works for the second part, see if you can figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much Brandon! :). Very helpful.